# subprocess: процесс ещё не завершён?

Tags: python, python-3.x, процесс, subprocess

Кто знает как с помощью модуля subprocess узнать - процесс ещё работает или нет?

```py
import subprocess
import time

process = subprocess.Popen(program, shell = True)
time.sleep(1)

#if process is running:
  process.kill()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274476/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-subprocess-is-still-running/43276598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import time

p = Popen('...')
poll = p.poll()

time.sleep(1)

if poll != None:
   process.kill()
```